# PowerBI - weekly share by col

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I´m trying to build a new measure, that show the share of "E_RATPROM"(numerical col) by "NombreCanal" and "fecha_ini_semana" defined by:
`fecha_ini_semana = 'calendar'[Date]-WEEKDAY('calendar'[Date],3)`

i´m working in a solution using AllExcept or AllSelected, but still cannot build it yet.

i'll appreciate any help..thanks in advance

[image: example_err]

***Update

i´ve tried the solution of Joao, but the measures dont return as expected;
[image: joao solution]

***Update 2

The issue was im using an aditional column for order, so this column had to be in the ALL expression..like Joao mentioned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate your total per week, you need to ignore any filters on NombreCanal:

```
// Measure 1
E_RATPROM Total = SUM('mpq_comercial mqp_sales_bloques'[E_RATPROM])

// Measure 2
total_semana = CALCULATE([E_RATPROM Total], ALL('mpq_comercial mqp_sales_bloques'[NombreCanal])

// Measure 3
ratio = DIVIDE([E_RATPROM Total], [total_semana])
```

Comment: thanks for the aproach, i tried with the measures, but still getting wrong result, i think the filter is messing with it. ![Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/8uEMBcE.jpg)

Comment: What filter (you have to make sure the All bit is excluding the column you have on the matrix columns)? Have a look at this demo https://www.dropbox.com/s/i23bka4mh8kyf55/demo.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Finally solved!! thanks for the workarround Joao, i´m using an aditional column to give order "NombreCanal" (like..if(NombreCanal = A, 1,if(NombreCanal = B,2)) so adding this col to the ALL expression solve the issue... really thanks for the helpl!